# Shortcode not executing in Divi Builder

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, shortcode

For all those Divi Builder/theme experts out there, I have a shortcode that runs perfectly fine in the normal Wordpress page editor but will not execute at all in a divi module(either text or code).

Is there anything special I need to be adding to get my shortcode to work correctly with divi builder?

Comment: Actually, the text module is a good way to include a shortcode. Sometimes it is even output visually. Alternatively, the code module should also work.

If the issue should not be clarified yet, then you can post the shortcode (with the code behind), then we can say more about it.

If you don't want to do that, you can also ask support: https://www.elegantthemes.com/contact/

Answer (score -2):

I will give you a list in troubleshooting this issue:

1. You have to check the browser console, there might be a conflict in the shorcode that you are using.
2. You have re-activate the plugin that you are using for the shortcode.
3. You have to `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in `wp_config.php` to see the error.

Once you see the error you can start fixing the problem.